# Setting cookies when php is accessed by android app

Tags: android

(I'm asking this partly for learning purposes, I realize what I'm trying to do might be entirely wrong!)

I have a php file on my website that handles log in and sets a cookie for the user if log in is successful. if setcookie() fails, I error out instead of displaying the rest of the page.

When I try to access this page using my android app (which uses HttpURLConnection with POST), the setcookie() fails. I'm guessing this is because the client isn't a browser and can't handle cookies.

so first of all, is there away for my app to be able to receive cookies from the server and store them? if not, how do you handle maintaining a login session with the user so you dont have to send a username and password, every time you want to access data from the server?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes before the workaround:

1. The function is called setcookie() not set_cookie()
2. Android browsers do support cookies afaik, so you probably should look into this further. Perhaps the format of your setcookie call is not valid?

If you can't use cookies, then the workaround is to simulate your own session mechanism by passing your cookie value as a url parameter on every request.

Comment: Thank you.
So for example create some hashed value on the server and send it to the client, and the client sends that each time it wants to access data?

Comment: Exactly.  This is not that far from how php sessions work.  You would want to have some sort of session table on the server that does a lookup for you, although I suspect you have something like that already that works with your current cookie.